# Removing unmatched text and building a table with the remaining matches

Tags: regex, export, match, data-cleaning

I have 30000 lines that look like the one below.

342800005013000 CON N GORE PT LOT 31 RP 11R2284 PT PART 1 RP 11R4541 PT PART 2

I would like to capture the 15 digit number at the beginning and any "11R***" numbers.

In Notepad++ I've used \d{15}|(11R\d*)* to match everything that I want. Ultimately I would like to get all the matched results into excel. What would be the best way to do so?

Thanks for your help.

[Notepad++ Matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vty0f.jpg)

Comment: I do not think  NPP regex approach will be nice. Say, you may use `(^\d{15}(?!\S)|(?<!\S)11R\d+(?!\S))|(?:(?!^\d{15}(?!\S)|(?<!\S)11R\d+(?!\S)).)+` and replace with `(?1$1\t)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one

```
(^[0-9]*)|(11R[0-9A-Za-z]*)
```

edit: check it now, the code formatting correctly displays the regex;

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I already have everything matched that I need (see image). I don't know how to pull out what I matched or erase what isn't matched? I can't seem to find any functions for pulling out matched characters....

Comment: In this case you could try using a negative lookahead with your regex and parse the string afterwards in order to remove the unneeded strings:
eg. in javascript: var newClass = userInput.replace(your regex,'');